# How to get the start and end of a day in T-SQL when daylight savings is enabled?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dst

I am currently working on a SQL Server script where we collect aggregated data on a daily basis for last 'n' days. In order to do this, we create a temp table with the start time and end time for all days for the last 'n' days. The code is as below.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Begin DATETIME, End DATETIME)

DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @begin DATETIME = DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 1, GETDATE()), 0)
DECLARE @end DATETIME = DATEADD(DD, 1, @begin)

WHILE @i <= @n
    INSERT INTO @Tbl
    SELECT @begin, @end

    SET @end = @begin
    SET @begin = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @end)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

We convert these dates to UTC by calling an inbuilt function which does the operation correctly as expected but throws an error for `November 4th 2018 00:00:00` as this is not a valid local time.

The issue with the above code is that it generates the date with the 0th hour of begin date and 0th hour of end date. Although some of these dates might be impractical due to daylight savings.

For example, if you consider the Brazil timezone, daylight saving was enabled on November 4th at `00:00:00` to `01:00:00` which makes the date `2018-11-04 00:00:00` incorrect to be converted to UTC.

Is there any known functions which can be used to pass a date and get the valid start time for the day and valid end time for the day in local time?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I believe you're coming at the problem backwards.  You should start with UTC and convert to/from local time at the display layer.  This will likely present you with different difficulties, but they should be easier to deal with.  Not posting an answer, as I don't really have one.

Comment: Since we need to get the customer data from their timezone, we start with local time instead of starting with UTC. If I start with UTC, removal of 24 hours for everyday would lead to time being set to 23:00:00 for 3rd November and 2nd November. Instead the difference calculated must be 23 hours for 4th November automatically instead of 24 hours.

Comment: We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. November 4th 2018 00:00:00 is invalid _for you_ but perfectly valid for someone who is not observing daylight savings time. I would ask for complete date time including the offset (`+xx:xx`) part and use it to convert the datetime to UTC.

Answer (score 2):

For local time start date and end date please use following code

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
SET @startDate=DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()),MONTH(getdate()),DAY(getdate()))
SET @endDate=getdate()
SELECT @startDate,@endDate
```

For UTC time please replace getdate() function with getutcdate() in above code

Answer (score 0):

GETUTCDATE()

Returns the UTC Date and Time

Comment: You can user use GETUTCDATE()  like GETGETDATE()